# AngularJS 1 - CSS is crashed when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My homepage when loaded as below: 
[image]

Originally, some rows was filled background color (blue color) by using ng-class, here is "row-answered-call" as you can see below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list" ng-class="{'row-answered-call': item.state === 'active', 'row-hovered' : item.hovered, 'row-selected': item.selected," ng-mouseover="highlight(item)" ng-dblclick="goToDetails(item)">


.row-answered-call  {
    background-color: g-hover !important;
}
```

The issue came after I switch to next tab, replace Type column with user photo, (this make height of row increasing as well). I used a variable (currentView) to keep track which td will be rendered:

```
<td ng-hide="currentView === 0" style="width: 8%">
    <div ng-if="item.type === CallTypes.VIDEO_CALL" class="table-group-thumb" style="background-image: url('{{item.thumbnailUrl}}')"></div>
    <div ng-if="item.type === CallTypes.MESSAGE" class="table-group-thumb"><img ng-src="{{ROOT_URL + ImagePaths.COLORED_MESSAGE}}" /></div>
    <div ng-if="item.type === CallTypes.VOICE_CALL" class="table-group-thumb"><img ng-src="{{ROOT_URL + ImagePaths.COLORED_VOICE_CALL}}" /></div></td>
<td style="width: 8%" ng-show="currentView === 0">
    <i ng-class="{'icon--guardian-phone': item.type === CallTypes.VOICE_CALL, 'icon--guardian-message': item.type === CallTypes.MESSAGE, 'icon--guardian-video-call': item.type === CallTypes.VIDEO_CALL}"></i>
</td>
```

[image]

Css was crashed now. Rows was not filled color correctly. I think this because the height of row was changed and css was not re-loaded after that.
Is anyone know about this issue please give me some advice or ideas to solve this issue.

---Updated on May 8, 2017 - 11:41AM

I merged 2 tds and change from ng-hide and ng-show to ng-if.

```
<td style="width: 8%">
     <div ng-if="currentView !== 0 && item.type === CallTypes.VIDEO_CALL" class="table-group-thumb" style="background-image: url('{{item.thumbnailUrl}}')"></div>
     <div ng-if=" currentView !== 0 && item.type === CallTypes.MESSAGE" class="table-group-thumb"><img ng-src="{{ROOT_URL + ImagePaths.COLORED_MESSAGE}}" /></div>
     <div ng-if=" currentView !== 0 && item.type === CallTypes.VOICE_CALL" class="table-group-thumb"><img ng-src="{{ROOT_URL + ImagePaths.COLORED_VOICE_CALL}}" /></div>
     <i ng-if="currentView === 0" ng-class="{'icon--guardian-phone': item.type === CallTypes.VOICE_CALL, 'icon--guardian-message': item.type === CallTypes.MESSAGE, 'icon--guardian-video-call': item.type === CallTypes.VIDEO_CALL}"></i>
</td>
```

Inspecting HTML as well as these tr, td don't see any issues, the background-color property contains correct value but in fact css still crashed as my above screenshots.

```
Thanks,
Ken
```

Comment: Try swapping your ng-hide/ng-show with ng-if (in all cases). ng-hide/ng-show destroys data inside them, which could be a cause of your issue. ng-if doesn't haven't that "feature".

Comment: Thank rrd, I tried as your suggestion but nothing happened. :(

Comment: @Ken Are you sure? What they suggested seem correct: `ng-hide="currentView === 0"` ==> `ng-if="currentView !== 0"` AND `ng-show="currentView === 0"` ==> `ng-if="currentView === 0"` (Because you currently have more columns for each row with causing the table to break, as it look like from the attached screenshot)

Comment: @Alon Eitan: Yes. That's exactly what I did! Do you have other solutions?

Comment: @Ken Unfortunately no, the only thing I can suggest is that you inspect the elements via developer tools and see what's going on with the HTML (This is how I debug issues like yours) It's hard to tell without a live fiddle

Comment: @alon-eitan I merged 2 tds together as well as changed ng-hide.ng-show to ng-if (please see my updated question).
Inspecting HTML as well as these tr, td don't see any issues, the background-color property contains correct value but in fact css still crashed as my above screenshots.

Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

.ng-class { 
            overflow: hidden}

Comment: Do you know anything about Angularjs, or css, or [how to write an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move **ng-class** (which filled background color for rows) from `<tr>` to **`<td>`** and that issue doesn't happen anymore.

Thanks for viewing my question.